# PgSQL trigger function on update and insert

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I have two tables **time_info** and **category**. I want to update the `temp_id` of **time_info** table whenever there is insertion of record or update of `duration` column of **time_info** table.

Here is the schema

**time_info**

- `id`
- `name` - text
- `duration` - smallint NOT NULL
- `temp_id` - integer

**category**

- `id`
- `temp_id` - integer
- `duration` - smallint

The **category** table has some static records and those record's `temp_id`s need to be populated to **time_info** table based the condition `time_info.duration` = `category.duration`.

Example
**category**

| id | temp_id | duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 123 | 30 |
| 002 | 234 | 60 |
| 003 | 345 | 90 |

So if a record is added in **time_info** like

| id | name | duration | temp_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | abc | 60 |  |

Then trigger function should run and update the row as following

| id | name | duration | temp_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | abc | 60 | 234 |

Now if someone changes the `duration` in **time_info** to `90` then trigger function should run again and update the `temp_id` to `345`.

WHat I tried

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION update_time_info_temp_id() RETURNS trigger AS $update_time_info_temp_id$
    BEGIN
        UPDATE NEW  SET NEW.temp_id = subquery.temp_id
        FROM (SELECT * from category) AS subquery
        WHERE NEW.duration = subquery.duration; 

        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$update_time_info_temp_id$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER update_time_info_temp_id AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON time_info
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION update_time_info_temp_id();
```

But it doesn't seem to be working as expected

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to pgsql and infact sql. So becomes hard to implement all at first.

Comment: So stop and at least skim the extensive reference docs first maybe?

Comment: @RichardHuxton I tried from docs as well, its still not working. Edited the query in post as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out. This might fix the problem.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_time_info_temp_id()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
    value_to_update integer;
BEGIN
    SELECT temp_id INTO value_to_update
    FROM category
    WHERE duration = NEW.duration;
      
    UPDATE time_info
    SET temp_id = value_to_update
    WHERE id = NEW.id;

    RETURN NEW;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER update_time_info_temp_id_trigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF duration ON time_info
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION update_time_info_temp_id();
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a BEFORE trigger. That lets you avoid the UPDATE and just modify NEW. You can also avoid any work when the duration hasn't changed.

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TABLE category (id int PRIMARY KEY, temp_id int NOT NULL, duration int NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE time_info (id int, name text, duration int NOT NULL, temp_id int NULL);

INSERT INTO category VALUES
    (1, 123, 30)
    , (2, 234, 60)
    , (3, 345, 90)
;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tr_set_temp_id()
RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $$
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' OR NEW.duration IS DISTINCT FROM OLD.duration THEN
        NEW.temp_id := (SELECT temp_id FROM category WHERE duration = NEW.duration);
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trig_set_temp_id BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON time_info
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tr_set_temp_id();


INSERT INTO time_info VALUES (100, 'a', 30, NULL);
SELECT * FROM time_info;
UPDATE time_info SET duration = 60 WHERE id = 100;
SELECT * FROM time_info;

ROLLBACK;
```

Note that your schema, as defined, has a couple of oddities. The `category` table's `id` seems redundant - the way you are using it suggests to me `duration` is the actual primary key. In any case you definitely want to put a unique constraint on it. You normally wouldn't copy the `temp_id` over too - just join from the `time_info` if you needed it.

Oh, you've not said what should happen if the duration isn't in the category table either - you'll want to consider that.